Homogeneous function satisfies Mikhlin theorem
Hy all,
I want to understand some affirmation. If some function $m:\mathbb R^{n}\setminus  \{0\}$ is $n+2$ times continuously differentiable and homogeneous of degree $0$ then $m$ satisfies  $|\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}m(\xi)|\leq C|\xi|^{-|\alpha|}$ for all $|\alpha|\leq n+2$ and $\lambda>0$.
Here is my attempt, By definition if $m$ is homogeneous of degree $0$ then $m(\lambda\xi)=m(\xi)$ then $\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}m(\xi)= \partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}m(\lambda\xi)=\lambda^{|\alpha|}\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}m(\lambda\xi)$ hence rule chain. Therefore,
$\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}m(\lambda\xi)=\lambda^{-|\alpha|}\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}m(\xi)$. This mean that $\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}m(\xi)$ is homogeneous of degree $-|\alpha|$. How can i continued? If i work in some compact set i can estimate the derivative but how  ifinish the excercise with the estimate above. Can somebody give me a hint please?
Well, maybe have sense if i put
$|\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}m(\xi)|=|\lambda^{|\alpha|}\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}m(\lambda\xi)|\xi|^{|\alpha|}|\xi|^{-|\alpha|}|$ and try to work with this?
can i take supremum of $|\lambda^{|\alpha|}\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}m(\lambda\xi)|\xi|^{|\alpha|}$ ?
Thanks
